# Why body is not included in jmeter request?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

As the images show, we are sending some body in http sampler, but in result tree we are not seeing body as a part of request and hense it is failing.

**Sampler Screen Shot**
[image: Sampler]

**Result Tree Screen Shot**
[image]

Comment: How HTTP Header under request looks like? Are there any pre procesors that affect request?

Comment: no pre-processor are there.

Comment: @user7294900 sorry buddy, you were right, it was due to a http url re-writing modifier pre processor which was included by recording controller at thread level so unable to spot this preprocessor. thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only think of one possible option: you're [running your test in command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) and by default [JMeter results file configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config) request and response data are not saved

If you want to see request and response data for non-GUI tests executions you need to add the next lines to *user.properties* file:

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.responseHeaders=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.url=true
```

or add a Listener like [Simple Data Writer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Data_Writer) and choose what and where to store. See [How to Save Response Data in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-save-response-data-in-jmeter) article for more details.

If you're facing this behaviour in GUI mode - most probably there should be something in [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging), a WARN or ERROR line which contains the reason or at least a clue for the root cause of the issue.

Comment: Thank you Dmitri, yeah you were right. I was running it with GUI mode. on a second thought I opened debug panel and observed that it was going through a HTTP URL re-writing modifier preprocessor which was not intended ( even though I do not have idea on re-writing modifier ) so i disabled it and tried , it was showing